# Run make in BBEdit on an .Rmd file

Tags: bbedit

I have a document (an RMarkdown document) which I am editing in BBEdit. I am also using a `makefile` to compile the final document and also do some other things.

At the moment, I have a terminal window open in which I run `make html`, but this requires me to switch to the terminal window and back.

Is there (and I am sure there is - I am new to BBEdit and only scratching the surface) a way of running `make html` from within BbEdit, preferably using a "per folder or project defined" command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a couple of ways you might accomplish this.

1. Use a Shell Worksheet to run your `make html` command;
2. Write a `#!` (bash, Python, ruby, whatever) script to do the work, and place it in BBEdit's Scripts folder. BBEdit sets the environment up for `#!` scripts (you can read more about this in the manual), so your script could figure out what the appropriate directory is in which to run the `make html`, based on the path to the active document.

Comment: I like the idea of setting up a BBEdit Script - but it seems, that BBEdit scripts are (now?) apple scripts and not bash scripts? Is this correct?

Comment: You can certainly put Bash scripts (or Python scripts, or Ruby, or indeed anything with a #! line) into BBEdit's "Scripts" folder and run them from BBEdit's Scripts menu. It doesn't have to be an AppleScript.

Comment: OK - I have the script now and I can also see it. But how do I get the working directory? the file name? ... Unless I am missing it, the manual is only talking about Apple Scripts? (BBEdit 13.0.5)

Comment: OK - found it, but not in the manual. You can find the variables here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/bbedit/bash$20environment$20scripts$20menu%7Csort:date/bbedit/lcdQfdzPICw/RFNnoQAZAgAJ

Comment: The user manual contains a table of the variables; in the 13.0 user manual it's on page 346 (accessible from the Help menu). When a script is run, $PWD is set to the directory containing the script (if the script file exists on disk). This is mentioned on page 344 of the user manual.